# Image not POST-ing android

Tags: java, android, image

Not sure what is going on here, not getting any red errors, but the post for the image never occurs, it is not touching my servers...

Here is the error in orange:

```
01-18 06:36:48.372: W/InputEventReceiver(7867): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
01-18 06:36:48.372: W/InputEventReceiver(7867): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
01-18 06:36:48.372: I/Choreographer(7867): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-18 06:36:48.372: W/ViewRootImpl(7867): Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=287.0, y[0]=-358.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=5442878, downTime=5442722, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
01-18 06:37:31.392: I/uploadFile(7867): HTTP Response is : Internal Server Error: 500
01-18 06:37:31.522: E/Async Time(7867): Async entered POSTTTT
```

Here is the code:

```
private class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String webAddressToPost = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/wardrobe";

        // File sourceFile = new File(imageview);
        String fileName = "/sdcard/IMG_2016.JPG";
        File sourceFile = new File(fileName );

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        // private ProgressDialog dialog
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                wardrobe.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.e("Async Time", "Async entered 1 PREEE");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Log.e("Async Time", "Async entered DURINGG");
            try {
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(webAddressToPost);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                            + " F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                    imageTextSelect.setText(msg);
                    Toast.makeText(wardrobe.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.e("Async Time", "Async entered POSTTTT");
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file uploaded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have set the sdcard permision?

Comment: what permissions do I need to pull from it?

Comment: The error is on the server side (Internal Server Error: 500). If you can get more precise error information from the server, that would help. Most likely your request isn't in the format the server expects.

Comment: I think you are right the problem is that I am not sure how to retrieve it on the server side, because when calling req.body on the server side I am getting an empty object {}...

Answer (score 0):

Your giving directly as **sdcard** `String fileName = "/sdcard/IMG_2016.JPG";` may be that's the reason.

Try like below codes..

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                            "/IMG_2016.JPG";
```

Comment: I actually was not even using filename afterwards I was keeping it still as the buri, however after fixing that I still get the following error updated above

Comment: @Lion789 can you post that what is `buri`. that means content of `buri`.

Comment: well it is the path of the selected image, but i hardcoded the path to the sdcard because i was not sure if it kept error-ing because it is an emulator

Comment: @Lion789 did you gave read permission `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`